# stack level too deep (SystemStackError) -- Unsure Why I get this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm calling two files from a main file that runs a whole program, handlers.rb and core.rb when I run the main file, main.rb I get the following error.

```
handlers.rb:4: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

When I run handlers.rb I get the same error when I run core.rb I get

```
core.rb:6: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

core.rb has

```
require 'mail'
require 'json'
load './handlers.rb'
```

handlers.rb has

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
require 'json'
load './core.rb'
require 'mail'
```

I don't get why I'm getting these errors, any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `load` method recursively.  Load is not like `require` in that `require` will indeed let you only include the file once, where `load` will let you include the file any number of times.

The files core.rb and handler.rb refer to each other with `load`.

Answer (score 0):

"stack level too deep" is always an indication of recursive calls.

For example:

```
  def foo
    foo
  end
```

If you call this in irb you will get:

**SystemStackError: stack level too deep**

In your code you recursively load both files. load() does not like that. I would also advice against this when you do require()

Preferentially decide that only one file should load the other file, and then keep only that one load and not the other.

Comment: I got it all figured out, this is my first huge project with Ruby thank you guys for the insight. I appreciate it :)

Comment: >> def foo
>> foo
>> end
=> :foo  # So no, you will not necessarily get an error with that code.  This is what happens when you run this code in IRB on Ruby 2.1, for example.